# How handle scopes OAuth 2.0 Google and Vert.x

Tags: java, http, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, vert.x

I'm having some issues when implementing OAuth2.0 Google and Vertx. I'm trying to make a simple example where user just have to ligon with google and after that we print a message on screen with the user name and email:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new MainVerticle());
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    final String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";

    final String CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";
    
    OAuth2Auth authProvider = GoogleAuth.create(vertx, CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET);


    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    OAuth2AuthHandler authHandler = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(vertx, authProvider, "http://localhost:8080/callback").withScopes(List.of("email", "profile"));


    authHandler.setupCallback(router.route("/callback"));


    router.route("/login").handler(authHandler);

    router.get("/callback").handler(ctx -> {

      String code = ctx.request().getParam("code");
      System.out.println(code);
      if(code != null){
        //Obtenemos token de acceso
        authProvider.authenticate(new Oauth2Credentials(new JsonObject().put("code", code)), res -> {
          if(res.succeeded()){
            //Almacenamos el usuario
            User user = res.result();
            ctx.setUser(user);
            ctx.put("token", user.principal());
            ctx.response().putHeader("location", "/protected").setStatusCode(302).end();
          }else {
            System.out.println("Error de authentication");
            ctx.fail(401);
          }
        });
      }else {
        //El usuario ha denegado los permisos
        System.out.println("El usuario ha denegado los permisos");
        ctx.fail(401);
      }
    });

    router.route("/protected").handler(RedirectAuthHandler.create(authProvider, "/login"));

    router.route("/protected").handler(ctx ->{

      if(ctx.user() != null){
        // Usuario identificado
        JsonObject profile = ctx.user().principal();
        String name = profile.getString("name");
        String email = profile.getString("email");
        ctx.response().end("Bienvenido, "  + name + " con email " + email);
      }
      }

    );


    router
      .get("/")
        .handler(ctc -> ctc.response()
          .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
          .end("Hello<br><a href=\"/login\">Protected by Google</a>"));

    vertx.
      createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080, http -> {
      if (http.succeeded()) {
        startPromise.complete();
        System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 8080");
      } else {
        startPromise.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

After logging in with google and accepting the permissions when calling the calback I always get this error and it throw a 403 Forbidden

```
HTTP server started on port 8080
mar 15, 2023 9:58:57 A. M. io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext
GRAVE: Unhandled exception in router
java.lang.IllegalStateException: principal scope != handler scopes
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.OAuth2AuthHandlerImpl.postAuthentication(OAuth2AuthHandlerImpl.java:349)...
```

Comment: Make sure that the scopes you define in authHandler and the scopes requested from the user (which are defined in the Google Cloud Console) match exactly.

Comment: Hey Mojtaba, yes I have added on OAuth consent screen the scopes "./auth/userinfo.email" and "./auth/userinfo.profile" to my app

Comment: You have to put the full scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile